# run time creating file and writing content

Tags: python, file, io

I am trying to create file run time and writing to it.

```
        file_name = 'result'
        fp = open(str(file_name), 'w')
        fp.write(partial_data+'\n\n')
        fp.close()
```

This works fine.

But when I tried -

```
            partial_data = simplejson.dumps(data, indent=4, skipkeys=True, sort_keys=True)
            file_name = 'result_'+str(url)+'.txt'
            fp = open(str(file_name), 'w')
            fp.write(partial_data+'\n\n')
            #json.dump(partial_data, fp)
            fp.close()
```

It gives

```
IOError: (2, 'No such file or directory', 'result_http://www.yumzap.com.txt')
```

Any help for this?

Comment: You can't create a file with a `/` or `:` in file name.

Comment: @Selcuk: That's what I thought, but I tried to create a file with a `:` and it worked.  This is on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slashes are not valid for a filename.  Maybe use `str(url).strip("http://")`:

```
file_name = 'result_'+str(url).strip("http://")+'.txt'
```